# pandas create dataframe from two files

Tags: python, pandas

I have two txt files...Structure first one is:

```
:Data_list: 20160203_Gs_xr_1m.txt
:Created: 2016 Feb 04 0010 UTC
# Prepared by the U.S. Dept. of Commerce, NOAA, Space Weather Prediction Center
# Please send comments and suggestions to SWPC.Webmaster@noaa.gov 
# 
# Label: Short = 0.05- 0.4 nanometer
# Label: Long  = 0.1 - 0.8 nanometer
# Units: Short = Watts per meter squared
# Units: Long  = Watts per meter squared
# Source: GOES-13
# Location: W075
# Missing data: -1.00e+05
#
#         1-minute GOES-13 Solar X-ray Flux
# 
#                 Modified Seconds
# UTC Date  Time   Julian  of the
# YR MO DA  HHMM    Day     Day       Short       Long
#-------------------------------------------------------
2016 02 03  0000   57421      0     2.13e-09    4.60e-07
2016 02 03  0001   57421     60     1.84e-09    4.51e-07
2016 02 03  0002   57421    120     1.79e-09    4.52e-07
2016 02 03  0003   57421    180     1.58e-09    4.58e-07
2016 02 03  0004   57421    240     2.51e-09    4.56e-07
2016 02 03  0005   57421    300     4.30e-09    4.48e-07
2016 02 03  0006   57421    360     1.97e-09    4.47e-07
2016 02 03  0007   57421    420     2.46e-09    4.47e-07
2016 02 03  0008   57421    480     3.10e-09    4.51e-07
2016 02 03  0009   57421    540     3.24e-09    4.43e-07
2016 02 03  0010   57421    600     2.92e-09    4.34e-07
2016 02 03  0011   57421    660     2.42e-09    4.35e-07
2016 02 03  0012   57421    720     2.90e-09    4.40e-07
2016 02 03  0013   57421    780     1.87e-09    4.36e-07
2016 02 03  0014   57421    840     1.31e-09    4.37e-07
2016 02 03  0015   57421    900     2.50e-09    4.41e-07
2016 02 03  0016   57421    960     1.52e-09    4.42e-07
2016 02 03  0017   57421   1020     1.36e-09    4.41e-07
2016 02 03  0018   57421   1080     1.33e-09    4.35e-07
2016 02 03  0019   57421   1140     2.20e-09    4.37e-07
2016 02 03  0020   57421   1200     2.90e-09    4.53e-07
2016 02 03  0021   57421   1260     1.39e-09    4.75e-07
2016 02 03  0022   57421   1320     4.55e-09    4.67e-07
2016 02 03  0023   57421   1380     2.30e-09    4.58e-07
2016 02 03  0024   57421   1440     3.99e-09    4.53e-07
2016 02 03  0025   57421   1500     3.93e-09    4.40e-07
2016 02 03  0026   57421   1560     1.70e-09    4.34e-07
.
.
.
2016 02 03  2344   57421  85440     3.77e-09    5.00e-07
2016 02 03  2345   57421  85500     3.76e-09    4.96e-07
2016 02 03  2346   57421  85560     1.64e-09    4.97e-07
2016 02 03  2347   57421  85620     3.59e-09    5.04e-07
2016 02 03  2348   57421  85680     2.55e-09    5.04e-07
2016 02 03  2349   57421  85740     2.30e-09    5.11e-07
2016 02 03  2350   57421  85800     2.95e-09    5.09e-07
2016 02 03  2351   57421  85860     4.25e-09    5.02e-07
2016 02 03  2352   57421  85920     4.78e-09    5.02e-07
2016 02 03  2353   57421  85980     3.04e-09    5.01e-07
2016 02 03  2354   57421  86040     3.30e-09    5.10e-07
2016 02 03  2355   57421  86100     2.22e-09    5.16e-07
2016 02 03  2356   57421  86160     4.12e-09    5.15e-07
2016 02 03  2357   57421  86220     4.25e-09    5.16e-07
2016 02 03  2358   57421  86280     3.48e-09    5.20e-07
2016 02 03  2359   57421  86340     4.19e-09    5.27e-07
```

And second one:

```
:Data_list: 20160204_Gs_xr_1m.txt
:Created: 2016 Feb 04 1301 UTC
# Prepared by the U.S. Dept. of Commerce, NOAA, Space Weather Prediction Center
# Please send comments and suggestions to SWPC.Webmaster@noaa.gov 
# 
# Label: Short = 0.05- 0.4 nanometer
# Label: Long  = 0.1 - 0.8 nanometer
# Units: Short = Watts per meter squared
# Units: Long  = Watts per meter squared
# Source: GOES-13
# Location: W075
# Missing data: -1.00e+05
#
#         1-minute GOES-13 Solar X-ray Flux
# 
#                 Modified Seconds
# UTC Date  Time   Julian  of the
# YR MO DA  HHMM    Day     Day       Short       Long
#-------------------------------------------------------
2016 02 04  0000   57422      0     4.85e-09    5.28e-07
2016 02 04  0001   57422     60     3.07e-09    5.29e-07
2016 02 04  0002   57422    120     4.48e-09    5.26e-07
2016 02 04  0003   57422    180     3.21e-09    5.17e-07
2016 02 04  0004   57422    240     4.23e-09    5.18e-07
2016 02 04  0005   57422    300     4.55e-09    5.21e-07
2016 02 04  0006   57422    360     3.30e-09    5.31e-07
2016 02 04  0007   57422    420     5.29e-09    5.49e-07
2016 02 04  0008   57422    480     3.14e-09    5.65e-07
2016 02 04  0009   57422    540     6.59e-09    5.70e-07
2016 02 04  0010   57422    600     6.04e-09    5.62e-07
2016 02 04  0011   57422    660     5.31e-09    5.62e-07
2016 02 04  0012   57422    720     6.04e-09    5.46e-07
2016 02 04  0013   57422    780     6.81e-09    5.51e-07
2016 02 04  0014   57422    840     6.59e-09    5.65e-07
2016 02 04  0015   57422    900     5.81e-09    5.62e-07
2016 02 04  0016   57422    960     4.63e-09    5.59e-07
2016 02 04  0017   57422   1020     3.05e-09    5.51e-07
2016 02 04  0018   57422   1080     3.26e-09    5.46e-07
2016 02 04  0019   57422   1140     4.59e-09    5.50e-07
2016 02 04  0020   57422   1200     3.38e-09    5.39e-07
2016 02 04  0021   57422   1260     2.43e-09    5.37e-07
2016 02 04  0022   57422   1320     5.31e-09    5.60e-07
2016 02 04  0023   57422   1380     5.63e-09    5.51e-07
2016 02 04  0024   57422   1440     5.18e-09    5.50e-07
2016 02 04  0025   57422   1500     7.06e-09    5.59e-07
2016 02 04  0026   57422   1560     5.01e-09    5.76e-07
2016 02 04  0027   57422   1620     7.17e-09    5.63e-07
2016 02 04  0028   57422   1680     5.74e-09    5.58e-07
2016 02 04  0029   57422   1740     5.55e-09    5.62e-07
2016 02 04  0030   57422   1800     4.99e-09    5.47e-07
2016 02 04  0031   57422   1860     5.49e-09    5.42e-07
2016 02 04  0032   57422   1920     2.14e-09    5.32e-07
2016 02 04  0033   57422   1980     2.48e-09    5.21e-07
2016 02 04  0034   57422   2040     4.35e-09    5.18e-07
2016 02 04  0035   57422   2100     4.84e-09    5.13e-07
2016 02 04  0036   57422   2160     3.12e-09    5.05e-07
2016 02 04  0037   57422   2220     1.18e-09    4.99e-07
2016 02 04  0038   57422   2280     1.59e-09    4.95e-07
```

Now I need create Pandas dataframe and name three columns...First-time that will be YYYY MM DD HHMM, second xra-penultimate column and xrb-last column...and I need find max of xrb with time ... I think that I know how find max with index with pandas but I dont know how create pandas dataframe...I have problem with 'Header' to 19th line...I need create dataframe from two files without header - only data. And is there any method how read data from some time to some time (time range)?
Thanks for help

edit:
I have this script:

```
import urllib2
import sys
import datetime
import pandas as pd


xray_flux = urllib2.urlopen('ftp://ftp.swpc.noaa.gov/pub/lists/xray/'+date+'_Gp_xr_1m.txt')
flux=xray_flux.read()
dataflux= open('xray_flux.txt','w')
dataflux.write(flux)
dataflux.close()

a=pd.read_csv("xray_flux.txt",header=None, sep=" ",error_bad_lines=False,skiprows=19)


print a
df=pd.DataFrame(a)

print df
```

Comment: Header of files has same number of rows?

Comment: if it is just 2 files, isn't it faster to just remove the headers manually? otherwise, you could do it in code by looking at the file line by line and deleting all lines which start with either ':' or '#'. that's the simplest solution that comes to mind, of course not general, but I doubt that there is an elegant general solution, and if you don't need it, don't spend time looking for it.

Comment: I think you can use `read_csv` with `skiprows=19`

Comment: yes it is olny 2 files but this script should be automatic...But this is not my problem ...I nedd create pandas dataframe from this files...

Comment: @jezrael thanks it is useful...but now how create pandas dataframe from two file with name columns...I edit my question ...Look at this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H%M')

#df1 = pd.read_csv('ftp://ftp.swpc.noaa.gov/pub/lists/xray/'+date+'_Gp_xr_1m.txt', 
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), 
                 sep="\s+", 
                 index_col=None, 
                 skiprows=19, 
                 parse_dates={'datetime': [0,1,2,3]}, 
                 header=None,
                 date_parser=dateparse)
print df1.head()
             datetime      4    5             6             7
0 2016-02-03 00:00:00  57421    0  2.130000e-09  4.600000e-07
1 2016-02-03 00:01:00  57421   60  1.840000e-09  4.510000e-07
2 2016-02-03 00:02:00  57421  120  1.790000e-09  4.520000e-07
3 2016-02-03 00:03:00  57421  180  1.580000e-09  4.580000e-07
4 2016-02-03 00:04:00  57421  240  2.510000e-09  4.560000e-07

#df = pd.read_csv('ftp://ftp.swpc.noaa.gov/pub/lists/xray/'+date+'_Gp_xr_1m.txt', 
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep="\s+", 
                 index_col=None, 
                 skiprows=19, 
                 parse_dates={'datetime': [0,1,2,3]}, 
                 header=None,
                 date_parser=dateparse)
print df2.head()
             datetime      4    5             6             7
0 2016-02-04 00:00:00  57422    0  4.850000e-09  5.280000e-07
1 2016-02-04 00:01:00  57422   60  3.070000e-09  5.290000e-07
2 2016-02-04 00:02:00  57422  120  4.480000e-09  5.260000e-07
3 2016-02-04 00:03:00  57422  180  3.210000e-09  5.170000e-07
4 2016-02-04 00:04:00  57422  240  4.230000e-09  5.180000e-07
```

```
df = pd.concat([df1[['datetime',6,7]],df2[['datetime',6,7]]])
df.columns = ['datetime','xra','xrb']
print df.head(10)
             datetime           xra           xrb
0 2016-02-03 00:00:00  2.130000e-09  4.600000e-07
1 2016-02-03 00:01:00  1.840000e-09  4.510000e-07
2 2016-02-03 00:02:00  1.790000e-09  4.520000e-07
3 2016-02-03 00:03:00  1.580000e-09  4.580000e-07
4 2016-02-03 00:04:00  2.510000e-09  4.560000e-07
5 2016-02-03 00:05:00  4.300000e-09  4.480000e-07
6 2016-02-03 00:06:00  1.970000e-09  4.470000e-07
7 2016-02-03 00:07:00  2.460000e-09  4.470000e-07
8 2016-02-03 00:08:00  3.100000e-09  4.510000e-07
9 2016-02-03 00:09:00  3.240000e-09  4.430000e-07
```

EDIT:

Also you can use parameter `usecols` in `read_csv` for filtering columns - you need only columns `datetime`, `6` and `7`. Then you can use all `df1` and `df2` in `pd.concat`:

```
#df1 = pd.read_csv('ftp://ftp.swpc.noaa.gov/pub/lists/xray/'+date+'_Gp_xr_1m.txt', 
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), 
                 sep="\s+", 
                 index_col=None, 
                 skiprows=19, 
                 parse_dates={'datetime': [0,1,2,3]}, 
                 header=None,
                 date_parser=dateparse,
                 usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7])
print df1.head()
             datetime             6             7
0 2016-02-03 00:00:00  2.130000e-09  4.600000e-07
1 2016-02-03 00:01:00  1.840000e-09  4.510000e-07
2 2016-02-03 00:02:00  1.790000e-09  4.520000e-07
3 2016-02-03 00:03:00  1.580000e-09  4.580000e-07

#df2 = pd.read_csv('ftp://ftp.swpc.noaa.gov/pub/lists/xray/'+date+'_Gp_xr_1m.txt', 
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep="\s+", 
                 index_col=None, 
                 skiprows=19, 
                 parse_dates={'datetime': [0,1,2,3]}, 
                 header=None,
                 date_parser=dateparse,
                 usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7])
print df2.head()
             datetime             6             7
0 2016-02-04 00:00:00  4.850000e-09  5.280000e-07
1 2016-02-04 00:01:00  3.070000e-09  5.290000e-07
2 2016-02-04 00:02:00  4.480000e-09  5.260000e-07
3 2016-02-04 00:03:00  3.210000e-09  5.170000e-07
4 2016-02-04 00:04:00  4.230000e-09  5.180000e-07
```

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df.columns = ['datetime','xra','xrb']
print df
              datetime           xra           xrb
0  2016-02-03 00:00:00  2.130000e-09  4.600000e-07
1  2016-02-03 00:01:00  1.840000e-09  4.510000e-07
2  2016-02-03 00:02:00  1.790000e-09  4.520000e-07
3  2016-02-03 00:03:00  1.580000e-09  4.580000e-07
4  2016-02-03 00:04:00  2.510000e-09  4.560000e-07
5  2016-02-03 00:05:00  4.300000e-09  4.480000e-07
6  2016-02-03 00:06:00  1.970000e-09  4.470000e-07
7  2016-02-03 00:07:00  2.460000e-09  4.470000e-07
8  2016-02-03 00:08:00  3.100000e-09  4.510000e-07
9  2016-02-03 00:09:00  3.240000e-09  4.430000e-07
```

Comment: What columns do you need? `4,5,6,7`?

Comment: is there some method how create dataframe from two files?

Comment: Yes, the best is `pd.concat`